# Error when passing workbook object to VBA form

Tags: excel, vba, forms, ms-word

I am working on a VBA script with Microsoft Word that allows the user to select text that will be copied to the clipboard so that it can exported to an Excel file. The user will make a number of selections and finally indicate he/she is done when the contents of the clipboard will be copied to a template Excel file.

The form (`frmModeLessForInput`) is a modeless form.  The form has two buttons "Continue" and "Done". The user is allowed to navigate the document and place the cursor anywhere in the document. Then when "Continue" is pressed the form will call a subroutine (`Highlight_Sentence`) to copy the selected text to a "clipboard" variable. When "Done" is pressed control will be passed to called subroutine which will then copy the clipboard to the Excel file.

The problem I am having is that I don't seem to have correct code needed to pass workbook object in created in the MAIN MODULE to the form using a form property. 
Below is the code.  I have inserted comments in the code in the `Select_Sentence_Form_Test` and `cmdDone` subroutines where I am having the problem passing the workbook object.

Any assistance in resolving these problems is appreciated.  As VBA programming is a sideline for me I am still learning.

```
Option Explicit
Public str_clipboard As String
Public txt_active_document As String
Public i_how_many_sentences As Integer
Public str_active_document
Public str_Excel_Filename As String
Public i_starting_row_ID As Integer
Public i_rows_of_data As Integer
```

MAIN MODULE

```
Sub Master_Module_Test()
Dim oExcel As Object
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook 'Object
   Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
   str_Excel_Filename = "C:\Test\Excel_Template.xlsx"
   Documents.Open ("C:\Test\Doc_to_process.docx")
   oExcel.Workbooks.Open str_Excel_Filename
   i_how_many_sentences = 0
   i_starting_row_ID = 1
   Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
   Call Select_Sentence_Form_Test(wb)
End Sub

Sub Select_Sentence_Form_Test(wb_open As Workbook)
    Dim frm As frmModelessForInput
    Set frm = New frmModelessForInput
' At this point wb_open is instantiated, i.e. I get "Excel_Template.xlsx" for wb_open.name
' But this code gives me an error "Object or block not set".  If I leave this statement out then "Me.Book1.ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial..." in cmd_Done in the frmModelessForInput module gives the same error
    Set frmModelessForInput.Book1 = wb_open
    With frmModelessForInput
        .str_word_doc_filename = str_active_document
        .str_no_copied = "0"
        .Show False
    End With
    Set frm = Nothing
End Sub
```

Below is the code for the frmModelessForInput form

```
Option Explicit
Private m_Book1 As Workbook


Public Property Get Book1() As Workbook
   Set Book1 = m_Book1
End Property

Public Property Set Book1(ByRef Value As Workbook)
   Set m_Book1 = Value
End Property

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    'Position the form near the top-left of the window
    'So that the user can work with the document
    Me.Top = Application.ActiveWindow.Top + 15
    Me.Left = Application.ActiveWindow.Left + 15
End Sub

Private Sub cmdContinue_Click()
 Dim str_clipboard, str_clipboard_line As String
       Call Highlight_Sentence(str_clipboard_line)
        i_how_many_sentences = i_how_many_sentences + 1 'Problem: VBA reports i_how_many_sentences as undefined even though it is a Public variable 
        frmModelessForInput.str_no_copied = i_how_many_sentences  'Same Problem
    str_clipboard = str_clipboard + str_clipboard_line 'Problem: each time I select a new text/sentence str_clipboard does not contain the contents of the previous selection
End Sub



Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    b_abort = True
Unload frmModelessForInput
End Sub

Private Sub cmdContinue_Click()
 Dim str_clipboard_line As String
 Dim i_row_number As Integer
 i_row_number = i_how_many_sentences + i_starting_row_ID
 i_how_many_sentences = i_how_many_sentences + 1
 Call Highlight_Sentence_Test(str_clipboard_line, i_row_number)
 frmModelessForInput.str_no_copied = i_how_many_sentences
 str_clipboard = str_clipboard + str_clipboard_line
End Sub

Private Sub cmdDone_Click()
 '  When the "Done" button is pressed the contents of the str_clipboard variable is copied to the Windows clipboard
    Dim str_filename As String
    str_filename = getName(str_Excel_Filename)
    MsgBox "I will now copy the data to the Excel file."
    Call SendToClipboard(str_clipboard) 'This sub puts the contents of str_clipboard into the Windows clipboard
    ' Uses the Book1 property --- this is the code line that produces the error "Object or block variable not set.  Activeworkbook.name shows that Excel_Template.xlsx is active
    Me.Book1.ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
    Unload frmModelessForInput
    MsgBox "Done pasting data to: " & getName(str_Excel_Filename)
End Sub




Private Sub Highlight_Sentence(clipboard As String, i_row_no As Integer)
    Dim txt_sentence, txt_page_no As String
    Dim txt_section_index As String
    With Selection
     ' Collapse current selection.
     .Collapse
     ' Expand selection to current sentence.
     .Expand Unit:=wdSentence
    End With
    clipboard = i_row_no & vbTab & txt_sentence & vbCrLf
End Sub
```

Comment: `Workbooks.Open` returns the opened workbook. Use `Set wb = .Workbooks.Open(str_Excel_Filename)` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`. Also, if you're using late binding, why is `oExcel` declared as `Object`?

Comment: I tried this code but had the same error.  In the `Select_Sentence_Form_Test` sub I have verified that `Set frmModelessForInput.Book1 = wb_open` properly sets workbook to the property.  But when I get to `cmdDone_Click` I get the following error when I try to validate `frmModelessForInput.Book1.Name` before I execute `Me.Book1.ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True`

'Error: Automation error: the callee [not server application] is not available and disappeared;...'